# Есть ли библиотека для обращения математических преобразований в Python?

Tags: python, математика

Есть проект в котором надо есть много относиельно простых математических пребразований. Так-же для каждого преобразования необходимо создвать и хранить обратное преобразование. 
Хочется иметь инструмент, который бы автоматически строил обратное преобразование. 
Например, чтобы преобразование 5*x + 10 записывалось как

```
transformation = Transformation(MultiplyBy(5), Add(10))
transformed_4 = transformation(4)
```

но при этом, чтобы обратное преобразование могло быть выполненно примерно так

```
restored_4 = transformation.restore(transformed_4)
assert restored_4 == 4 # не будем учитывать пока ошибки округления
```

Быть может есть для такой задачи готовые решения?

Comment: Нелинейные преобразование тоже есть. Все обратимы в рабочей области определения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Модуль [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/index.html) позволяет работать с математическими выражениями в аналитическом виде (с символами).

Пример:

```
from sympy import symbols, solve, simplify, factor
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import (
  parse_expr, 
  standard_transformations, 
  implicit_multiplication,
  implicit_multiplication_application)

trf = (
  standard_transformations +
  (implicit_multiplication_application,))

x, y, z, t = symbols('x y z t')

formula_str = "5*x + 10"
formula = parse_expr(formula_str, transformations=trf)
print(formula)
#5*x + 10

# подставим 4 вместо `x`:    
res = formula.subs(x, 4)
print(res)
#30

# решение уравнения: `5*x + 10 = 0`
print(solve(formula))
#[-2]

# решение уравнения: `5*x + 10 = 30` или `5*x + 10 - 30 = 0`
print(solve(formula_str + f" - {res}"))
#[4]
```

---

Другие примеры:

```
In [94]: [r for r in solve('x**4-(x-2)**2') if r.is_real]
Out[94]: [-2, 1]

In [95]: simplify('sin(x)**2 + cos(x)**2')
Out[95]: 1

In [96]: factor('x**4-(x-2)**2')
Out[96]: (x - 1)*(x + 2)*(x**2 - x + 2)

In [100]: simplify('sin(x)**2 / (1 - sin(x)**2)')
Out[100]: tan(x)**2
```

---

производные и интегралы:

```
In [128]: from sympy import diff, integrate

In [129]: diff('log(x**2)')
Out[129]: 2/x

In [130]: integrate('2/x')
Out[130]: 2*log(x)
```

Comment: Крутая штука! После её solve остаётся только отфильтровать ответы в соответсвии с начальной областью определения.

Comment: @griddic, да, `sympy` - мощный модуль. Можно интересные вещи делать... ;)

Answer (score 0):

А не проще ли самому написать класс и с ним работать, раз уж потребности не так велики?
Например так (x=5,2x+20) :

```
class Transform():
    def __init__(self,x=0,mul=1,add=0):
        self.x = x
        self.mul = mul
        self.add = add
    def calculate (self):
        self.res = self.x*self.mul + self.add
        return self.res
    def reverse (self):
        self.reverse = (self.res-self.add)/self.mul
        return self.reverse
    def expose (self):
        return "{}x{}+{}".format(self.x, self.mul, self.add)

eq1 = Transform(5, 2, 20)
print(eq1.calculate())
print(eq1.expose())
print(eq1.reverse())
```

Получим:

```
30
5x2+20
5.0
```

Comment: и что писать класс для каждой формулы, которую нельзя представить в виде линейной функции?

Comment: @MaxU В первом приближении я решил не считать нелинейные функции "относительно простыми математическими преобразованиями". Но, тут уж хозяин - барин.

Comment: Вообще, да, если бы преобразования были только линейными, то, действительно, всё можно было бы свести к одной формуле. Но нелинейные преобразования тоже присутствуют.