# Как превратить строку в математический символ

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется 3 строковых переменных a, b, z. a, b - это переменные чисел, z - знак мат. операции. Как можно его превратить в понятный для компилятора вид
Пробовал так:

```
print(a + ' ' + z + ' ' + b + ' ' + '=' + ' ' + str(float(a) + float(z) + float(b)))
```

Например a = 5.5, b = 2.3, z = +. Следовательно должно быть ответом число 7.8

Comment: И чем не устроил результат пробования?

Comment: Programm.py", line 42, in <module>
    print(a + ' ' + z + ' ' + b + ' ' + '=' + ' ' + str(float(a) + float(z) + float(b)))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '+'

Comment: А что вы ожидали получить в результате float(z), если z это "+"?

Comment: ну я и задал вопрос, чтобы понять как можно исправить эту ошибку

Comment: Эту - никак. Нужно менять логику программы. Тут много про калькуляторы, поищите.

Comment: А как поменять логику этой программы? Можно намек.

Comment: смотреть какой символ находится в z и в зависимости от этого вычислять результат.

Comment: @Александр, [посмотрите здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/907712/%d0%95%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-python), возможно вам будет интересно...

Answer (score 1):

Проверяете символ и в зависимости от этого вычисляете результат.
Также можно использовать функцию `exec`, но это очень опасно, не рекомендую так делать.

*Пример:*

```py
a = 5.5
b = 2.3
z = '+'

if z == '+':
    print(a + b)
elif z == '-':
    print(a - b)

# Опасно
cmd = r'print({} {} {})'.format(a, z, b)
exec(cmd)
```

Comment: А можете дать ссылку где можно про это почитать или сами объясните почему это опасно и так не стоит делать?

Comment: @Александр Потому что эта команда исполняет любой переданный ей код. Если пользователь вместо числа ввёдет команду удаления Вашей системы, то Python покорно это сделает. Почитать об этом можете [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/221937/) (речь идёт об `eval`, но это почти одно и то же)